# Is it possible that the following integral is $0$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, integration

Given any integer $n\geqslant1$, let $E,F$ be two subsets of $\{\{i,j\}:1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n\}$ such that every two sets in $F$ are disjoint.

It is not difficult to see that
$$\int_{1<|z|<2}\prod_{\{i,j\}\in E}\left(\frac{z_i}{z_j}+\frac{z_j}{z_i}-2\right)dz\neq0$$
where $|z|=\sqrt{|z_1|^2+\cdots+|z_n|^2}$ and $dz$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

My question is whether it is possible that
$$\int_{1<|z|<2}\prod_{\{i,j\}\in E}\left(\frac{z_i}{z_j}+\frac{z_j}{z_i}-2\right)\prod_{\{i,j\}\in F}|z_i-z_j|^2dz=0.$$
I would be very grateful for thoughts on how to tackle this problem. Any idea is welcome!